# Random row selection but with distinct values for a subset of columns

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I have a table that looks like this :

```
Key1 | Key2 | Key3 | Data  |
-----|------|------|-------| 
   1 |   1  |   1  |   a   |
   1 |   1  |   2  |   b   |
   1 |   2  |   1  |   c   |
   1 |   2  |   2  |   d   |
   2 |   1  |   1  |   e   |
   2 |   1  |   2  |   f   |
   2 |   2  |   1  |   g   |
   2 |   2  |   2  |   h   |
---------------------------|
```

Here is some code to create that example table :

```
CREATE TABLE Example(
Key1 int,
Key2 int,
Key3 int,
Data varchar(1));

INSERT INTO Example(Key1,Key2,Key3, Data)
VALUES (1,1,1,'a'), 
(1, 1,2,'b'),
(1, 2,1,'c'),
(1, 2,2,'d'),
(2, 1,1,'e'),
(2, 1,2,'f'),
(2, 2,1,'g'),
(2, 2,2,'h');
```

I want to randomly select one whole row for each distinct pair of Key1 and Key2 values (one for the 1 / 1 pair, one for the 1 / 2 pair etc.) One possible result would be :

```
Key1 | Key2 | Key3 | Data  |
-----|------|------|-------| 
   1 |   1  |   1  |   a   |
   1 |   2  |   1  |   c   |      
   2 |   1  |   2  |   f   |
   2 |   2  |   1  |   g   |
---------------------------|
```

I can do this doing multiple queries, by first selecting all the Key1 and Key2 distinct pairs and then using those pairs to run an other query like

```
SELECT stuff FROM table WHERE Key1 = value1 AND Key2 = value2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`
```

But this gross approach needs to ask as many queries as existing pairs of Key1/Key2 and is taking forever since my table is huge.

I've read things about using subqueries, partition, group by, but I struggle to implement them.
I'm new to SQL and only need to use it for a specific project and I don't really have the time to learn it properly, so I would be very thankful if you guys could give me a hand.

Thanks
JC

Comment: Specify MySQL version

Comment: I just realised that Mysql and MariaDB are mutually exclusive, what I work with is MariaDB 10 then. I'll edit my question

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql). Even if you don't have time to learn SQL, may be you can find some time preparing sample data, which will help people answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @mustaccio, I added some code to generate the minimal and complete example I provided

Comment: This is a variant on "groupwise max", but with "rand" instead of "max".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MariaDB 10.3 supports window functions, so something like this would work:

```sql
select * from (
  select 
     t.*, -- all columns
     row_number() -- assign sequential numbers
     over ( -- within a "window"
        partition by k1, k2 -- determined by a unique combination of k1, k2
        order by rand() -- while ordering rows randomly within the partition
     ) as rn -- set the column alias  
  from test t 
) tt 
where rn = 1 -- select only the first row from each "window" (partition)
order by k1, k2, k3
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=122dd71475c5e51063b3923a77ebb257)